# Java 9 + Spring Boot + Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, java-9

I want to start simple project using Spring Boot version 2.0.0.M4 , Maven and JDK 9. 
I created structure:

[image]

In my pom .xml in "app" module I have:

```
<properties>
    <spring-boot-starter-web.version>2.0.0.M4</spring-boot-starter-web.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot-starter-web.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My module-info.java is simple:

```
module app {
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
}
```

And I am trying to run simple server:

```
package com.resizer.app;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

When I am trying to run the server during compilation I get multiple errors:

```
Error:java: the unnamed module reads package javax.annotation from both tomcat.embed.core and javax.annotation.api
Error:java: the unnamed module reads package javax.annotation.sql from both tomcat.embed.core and javax.annotation.api
Error:java: the unnamed module reads package javax.annotation.security from both tomcat.embed.core and javax.annotation.api
Error:java: module spring.boot.starter reads package javax.annotation from both tomcat.embed.core and javax.annotation.api
Error:java: module spring.boot.starter reads package javax.annotation.sql from both tomcat.embed.core and javax.annotation.api
Error:java: module spring.boot.starter reads package javax.annotation.security from both tomcat.embed.core and javax.annotation.api
Error:java: module spring.boot reads package javax.annotation from both tomcat.embed.core and javax.annotation.api
Error:java: module spring.boot reads package javax.annotation.sql from both tomcat.embed.core and javax.annotation.api
Error:java: module spring.boot reads package javax.annotation.security from both tomcat.embed.core and javax.annotation.api
Error:java: module spring.boot.starter.logging reads package javax.annotation from both tomcat.embed.core and javax.annotation.api
Error:java: module spring.boot.starter.logging reads package javax.annotation.sql from both tomcat.embed.core and javax.annotation.api
Error:java: module spring.boot.starter.logging reads package javax.annotation.security from both tomcat.embed.core and javax.annotation.api
Error:java: module logback.classic reads package javax.annotation from both tomcat.embed.core and javax.annotation.api
Error:java: module logback.classic reads package javax.annotation.sql from both tomcat.embed.core and javax.annotation.api
```

Am I doing something wrong with the module-info? How to prevent this from happening? Should I exclude some dependencies?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/44842117/3530898