# How do I resolve reading package javax.transaction.xa from both javax.transaction.api and java.sql?

Tags: java, java-9, java-10, java-module

I'm aware of [How to resolve module reads package error in java9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44697738/how-to-resolve-module-reads-package-error-in-java9/47239794) but I'm still having trouble figuring out how to resolve split packages. For example, I have Spring Boot application in which I'm getting this error (among many many others):

```
Error:java: module spring.security.core reads package javax.transaction.xa from both javax.transaction.api and java.sql
```

My module looks like this:

```
module tech.flexpoint.dashmanserver {
    requires tech.flexpoint.dashmancommon;

    requires bcprov.jdk15on;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.core;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;
    requires hibernate.core;
    requires java.persistence;
    requires java.sql;
    requires java.validation;
    requires javax.transaction.api;
    requires spring.data.commons;
    requires spring.beans;
    requires spring.data.jpa;
    requires spring.jdbc;
    requires spring.security.core;
    requires spring.tx;
    requires spring.web;
}
```

I need both `javax.transaction.api` and `java.sql`. How do I resolve this split package issue in particular?

Comment: You need to upgrade to JTA 1.3, it drops the javax.transaction.xa package.