# How do I write module-info requires statement from GAV coordinates of a non-modular dependency?

Tags: java, java-11, java-module, java-platform-module-system, module-info

I am converting a legacy java app to a modular one. It is a Gradle project, and the dependencies look like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jopendocument:jOpenDocument:1.3'
    implementation 'xom:xom:1.3.2'
}
```

In the App class, my imports are:

```java
import nu.xom.Document;
import nu.xom.Element;
import nu.xom.Serializer;
import org.jopendocument.dom.spreadsheet.MutableCell;
import org.jopendocument.dom.spreadsheet.Sheet;
import org.jopendocument.dom.spreadsheet.SpreadSheet;
```

I want to create a module-info.java file. But when I do, my app won't compile because the `requires` directives are wrong in the module-info file.

```java
module weapongeneration4dusty.main {
    requires xom;
    requires jOpenDocument;
    exports com.hymerfania.rptools.maptool.meta.tablegeneration;
}
```

The module names `xom` and `jOpenDocument` are insufficient. But I don't know what they should be for these dependencies, nor how to reconfigure Gradle; if that's what I need to do.

When I omit either `requires` statement, the corresponding `import`s fail to resolve. I have not looked in the JAR files. But I don't think either artifact is modular.

I'm using Gradle 5.6.2 and I'm targeting Java 11.

Comment: If `xom` and `jOpenDocument` are unnamed modules, you don't need to put `requires xom` there. Check if they have module-info files

Comment: If I omit the requires statements, app does not compile because the imports cannot be resolved. I'll edit the question to point that out. Thanks!

Comment: I just upgraded the gradlew to 6.5, and now I get split packages errors "error: the unnamed module reads package org.w3c.dom from both jOpenDocument and xml.apis" That is probably progress, but I can only guess about how to fix this new problem. First I will try to concoct a "exclude group" statement in the build.gradle. But I am completely in the dark.

Comment: Possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44697738/how-to-resolve-module-reads-package-error-in-java9 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358084/package-conflicts-with-automatic-modules-in-java-9

Comment: How did you eventually resolve your split package problem @Charlweed? An identical issue was resolved [*with this answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64072627/understanding-errors-with-jpms-modules/64124282#64124282).