# the unnamed module reads package dev.langchain4j.store.embedding from both langchain4j and langchain4j.core

Tags: java-module

I am trying to use JPMS in a project and get this dreaded error:

```
the unnamed module reads package dev.langchain4j.store.embedding from both langchain4j and langchain4j.core
```

I understand what the error means. I am dealing with a split package. But how do I fix it? I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44697738/how-to-resolve-module-reads-package-error-in-java9) and other threads on the topic but don't see how to fix it in this scenario. My constraints:

- I am dealing with a 3rd party library. 3rd party = I cannot modify its code in any way.
- I tried removing one of the modules in my `requires` clause in `module-info.java` but it gives me another series of errors. Looks like I really need both modules.
- I use Maven to build my project. I need a solution that shows how to fix my Maven build so it compiles without error.

I have uploaded complete sample project showing how to reproduce the problem [here](https://github.com/siddhsql/jpms-sample/tree/main)

Comment: hopefully both `langchain4j` and `langchain4j.core` are owned by the same source and you can follow up with them to make the changes at the source to fix this cleanly

Comment: There’s a contradiction between your attempts to edit `requires` clauses in a `module-info.java` and the error message talking about *the unnamed module*. If your code is loaded through the classpath anyway, why don’t you put the `langchain4j.jar` and `langchain4j.core.jar` into the classpath too, instead of trying to load them as modules?